# VLSM network design

Tags: cisco, routing, vlsm

I'm studying for the CCNA exam and I want to create a VLSM scheme using RIPv2 for the following (CCNA practice example):

- Network connecting 4 different locations
- Each switch is fa 0/0 on the router
- Every point-to-point serial connection is in the network is class C (192.168.1.0 )
- Network 172.20.0.0 for each location
- Use the lowest subnet number (zero is allowed)

Requirements for each location:

- Dallas - 500 hosts
- New York - 2000 hosts
- Chicago - 1000 hosts
- LA - 2000 hosts

Here's my design so far:
[image]

Do you see any flaws in this? How would you fix them? Or how would you design this?

Comment: Smells like homework.

Comment: Yeah, it was a practice question for the CCNA and I wanted to make sure I was starting off right.

Comment: http://www.gns3.net/phpBB/topic3382.html?sid=81633409141c15aaf5778e7858a847cd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switches:

```
New York --> LGA 172.20.0.0/21
Los Angeles --> 172.20.8.0/21
Dallas --> DFW 170.20.20.0/23
Chicago --> ORD 172.20.16.0/22
```

Routers:

```
192.168.1.13 ORD s0/1
192.168.1.14 LAX s0/0

192.168.1.1 DFW s0/0
192.168.1.2 LAX s0/1

192.168.1.5 DFW 0/1
192.168.1.6 LGA s0/0

192.168.1.9 LGA s0/1
192.168.1.10 ORD s0/0
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're asking us to do your homework... anyway, I do see some flaws in the subnetting.

Do you really understand how subnetting works ? It doesn't seem so.

[This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work) may help you to get the picture, but let's improve your design & skills:

- Dallas : 500 hosts => 512 => /23
- New York : 2000 hosts => 2048 => /21
- Chicago : 1000 hosts => 1024 => /22
- LA : 2000 hosts => 2048 => /21

On this part you're right. But here is the fault :

```
 172.20.0.1/23 = 172.20.0.0 -> 172.20.1.255
 172.20.0.1/22 = 172.20.0.0 -> 172.20.3.255
 172.20.4.1/21 = 172.20.0.0 -> 172.20.7.255
 172.20.6.1/21 = 172.20.0.0 -> 172.20.7.255
```

So all your networks are overlapping, which isn't good. **Each address must be unique**. So a correct design would be like this :

```
 172.20.0.0/21  = 172.20.0.0  -> 172.20.7.255
 172.20.8.0/21  = 172.20.8.0  -> 172.20.15.255
 172.20.16.0/22 = 172.20.16.0  -> 172.20.19.255
 172.20.20.0/23 = 172.20.20.0 -> 172.20.21.255
```

You can start from the largest networks to the smallest, with the starting address being the last+1 from the previous network.

Comment: The 172.20.16.0/22 should = 172.20.16.0 ...right?

Comment: @에이바: indeed, copy/paste error :)

Answer (score 2):

Your Serial Connections subnet is off: You are specifying a 192.168.1.0/30 for 4 point to point connections @ 2 addresses each = 8 needed IPs.  A /30 CIDR will only yield 2 available host addresses (enough for only one connection).  You should have a single /30 subnet for each point to point:

```
192.168.1.0/30  = 192.168.1.0  -> 192.168.1.3  (Use .1 & .2)
192.168.1.4/30  = 192.168.1.4  -> 192.168.1.7  (Use .5 & .6)
192.168.1.8/30  = 192.168.1.8  -> 192.168.1.11 (Use .9 & .10)
192.168.1.12/30 = 192.168.1.12 -> 192.168.1.15 (Use .13 & .14)
```

Comment: Your diagram is still technically wrong though.

Comment: How so?  I posted a new answer the the diagram.

Comment: Yes, the new diagram is still technically incorrect.  You are only specifying one of the four serial connection subnets.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/VuhGX.png